# How to call a Swift function in Rust?

Tags: objective-c, swift, rust, ffi

I have a function written in Swift that I want to call from Rust. I've tried exposing it through Objective-C, however I continue to get errors from `ld` saying it can't find `_foo`. The Rust project is linked to the Swift project by compiling the Rust project as a staticlib.

#### foo.h

```c
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t foo_bridge(uint8_t);
```

#### foo.m

```c
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Foo-Swift.h>

uint8_t foo_bridge(uint8_t byte) {
    return foo(byte);
}
```

#### bar.swift

```
public func foo(byte: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
    return byte * 2
}
```

#### src/lib.rs

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn foo_bridge(byte: u8) -> u8;
}
```

#### Bar-Bridging-Header.h

```c
#import "foo.h"
```

#### Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "foo"
version = "0.1.0"

[lib]
name = "foo"
crate-type = ["staticlib"]
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. This is a linker error, but you did not specify any information about how you are linking the swift project into the Rust project.

Comment: @ker Updated. I link by compiling the rust project as a staticlib.

Comment: So I misunderstood... you are linking the Rust project in your swift project? How are you doing that in swift? Please post the full command line. It's very unclear to me what you are linking where and how the error occurs.

Comment: Full command line? This is in XCode I just created a Objective-C bridging header, and that works fine. You can read more how that works here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-an-ios-app-in-rust-part-1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue here is attempting to call a bare Swift function from Objective-C, which isn't supported.

If you check the `Foo-Swift.h` header you'll find that the `foo()` function isn't present, which indicates that the symbol for it, `_foo`, won't be available at runtime either.

The solution is to put the `foo()` function inside something that can be called from Objective-C, like a class deriving from NSObject:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    class func foo(byte: UInt8) -> UInt8 {
        return byte * 2
    }
}
```

Once you do that, you'll find the `Foo-Swift.h` header now has an interface for it:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
+ (uint8_t)fooWithByte:(uint8_t)byte;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Since we know it's available from Objective-C now, we can call it like this:

```
uint8_t foo_bridge(uint8_t byte) {
    return [Foo fooWithByte:byte];
}
```